# select2 .select2('data', {id: '', text: ''}) is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to pre select the select2 items using .select2('data', {id: 'VG', text: 'Virginia'}); but it is not working.
Can you experts help me ?
where it is getting wrong ?
please note i want preselect item using id and text both or only text.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var $states = $(".js-source-states");
      var statesOptions = $states.html();
      $states.remove();
    
      $(".js-states").append(statesOptions);

      
    var $basicMultiple = $(".js-example-basic-multiple");
    $basicMultiple.select2({placeholder: 'Select AN option',allowClear: true });
    $basicMultiple.select2('data', {id: 'VG', text: 'Virginia'});
   
    });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<select class="js-source-states">
  <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Eastern Time Zone">
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VG">Virginia</option>
    <option value="">West Virginia</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

<div class="container">
    <select class="js-example-basic-multiple js-states form-control" style="width: 50%" multiple="multiple"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change select2 value programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38773041/how-to-change-select2-value-programmatically)

Comment: @Sanjay you still looking for answer or above mentioned URL worked for you?

Comment: Yes above URL not work for me.